# softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer downloads wrong installer

Tags: macos, software-update, big-sur, ventura

The Softwareupdate-Tool downloads a BigSur installer, even though my Mac is already on Ventura. What causes this, is there a fix?
Does anybody know what version to specify to get then Ventura installer?

```
 softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you issue the command `softwareupdate --list-full-installers`, what do you get?  Also, what particular Mac do you have?

Answer (score 3):

The [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/softwareupdate.html) says it should fetch 'the latest' but it also says you can specify

e.g.
`softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 10.15.4`

tbh, these days I tend to use [MDS](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/mac-deploy-stick/), which just gives a clickable list of just about everything.

Comment: fetching an installer does not work for 13.5 "Install failed with error: Update not available"

Downloading a random MDS solution is not really an option for me.

Comment: MDS isn't exactly random, it uses the same sources. What Mac is it?